# jQuery: what is needed to remove closest with click on button

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-table, closest

I have an HTML table with one TH row and several TRs that are added dynamically. 
Each TR has a button in the last column.

What do I need so that by click on the button the closest TR gets removed from the table? 
I tried using `$(this).closest.remove()` but this didn't work so I assume I need to add IDs or something else here.

**A basic example table would look like the following:**

```
<table class='tableClass'>
    <tbody>
        <th>
            <td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td>
        </th>
        <tr>
            <td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td><button type='button' class='btnClass'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td><button type='button' class='btnClass'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td><button type='button' class='btnClass'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use :$(this).closest('tr').remove();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the `closest` function a selector. Try this:

```
$('.btnClass').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Also, your HTML is invalid as `th` should be a child of `tr`:

```
<table class='tableClass'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Text</th>
            <th>Text</th>
            <th>Text</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>
                <button type='button' class='btnClass'>Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>
                <button type='button' class='btnClass'>Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>
                <button type='button' class='btnClass'>Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/r8RAK/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip with wrapping the header row properly. I changed this now. Regarding the selector, I tried this but it still does nothing. Could it make any difference that my table is inside a div ?

Comment: @user2571510 the parent `div` shouldn't make a difference. You can see it working in the fiddle. Are your table rows being dynamically appended? You would need a different `click` hook if that is the case. Let me know and I'll show you an example.

Comment: Yes, they are. This hint helped me to fix it. I now changed the function to $(document).on('click', '.btnClass', function() which works fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`.closest( selector )`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest1) properly like:

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Actually in your code:

```
$(this).closest.remove()
            ___^___
```

you are missing both the opening and closing parenthesis `()` and the selector `tr`.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/cpvh9/

```
$(".btnClass").click(function(){
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    });
```

Comment: Just FYI, this would remove *all* parent `tr` elements. If the table is nested, that could cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for this as well. Same result as above clicking on one of the delete buttons seems to do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

From your HTML code it looks like you want to remove parent TR, try this

```
$(".btnClass").click(function(){
    $(this).parents("tr:first").remove();
});
```